# Nested If statement in a while statement always chooses the first If statement

Tags: c++

To starts off, I am pretty new to C++. I am working on a project just for fun but keep running into a problem (see code below), no matter what my input word is, the code assigns the statRollArray value to the wisdom int. I have tried all of the different input methods, but it always acts as if I put in "wisdom".  Why is this? Any help is appreciated!

```
while (charisma == 0 || strength == 0 || dexterity == 0 || intelligence == 0 || wisdom == 0 || consitution == 0) {

    cout << "Where would you like to assign your roll of " << statRollArray[chooseStatNumber] << "?" << endl;
    if (dexterity == 0) {
        cout << "Dexterity";
    }
    if (intelligence == 0) {
        cout << " Intelligence";
    }
    if (strength == 0) {
        cout << " Strength";
    }
    if (wisdom == 0) {
        cout << " Wisdom";
    };
    if (charisma == 0) {
        cout << " Charisma";
    }
    if (consitution == 0) {
        cout << " Constitution"
             << endl;
    }
    string choice = "";
    cin >> choice;
    if (choice == "wisdom" || "Wisdom" || "Dexterity" || "dexterity" || "Strength" || "strength" || "Intelligence" || "intelligence"
        || "Charisma" || "charisma" || "Constitution" || "constitution") {

        if (choice == "wisdom" || "Wisdom") {
            if (wisdom == 0) {
                wisdom = statRollArray[chooseStatNumber];
                chooseStatNumber += 1;
                continue;
            }
        }
        else {
            cout << "Wisdom already has been assigned!" << endl;
            continue;
        }
        if (choice == "Dexterity" || "dexterity") {
            if (dexterity == 0) {
                dexterity = statRollArray[chooseStatNumber];
                chooseStatNumber += 1;
                continue;
            }
        }
        else {
            cout << "Dexterity already has been assigned!" << endl;
            continue;
        }

        if (choice == "strength" || "Strength") {
            if (strength == 0) {
                strength = statRollArray[chooseStatNumber];
                chooseStatNumber += 1;
                continue;
            }
        }
        else {
            cout << "Strength already has been assigned!" << endl;
            continue;
        }

        if (choice == "intelligence" || "Intelligence") {
            if (intelligence == 0) {
                intelligence = statRollArray[chooseStatNumber];
                chooseStatNumber += 1;
                continue;
            }
        }
        else {
            cout << "Intelligence already has been assigned!" << endl;
            continue;
        }

        if (choice == "charisma" || "Charisma") {
            if (charisma == 0) {
                charisma = statRollArray[chooseStatNumber];
                chooseStatNumber += 1;
                continue;
            }
        }
        else {
            cout << "Charisma already has been assigned!" << endl;
            continue;
        }
        if (choice == "constitution" || "Constitution") {
            if (consitution == 0) {
                consitution = statRollArray[chooseStatNumber];
                chooseStatNumber += 1;
                continue;
            }
        }
        else {
            cout << "Constitution already has been assigned!" << endl;
            continue;
        }
    }
    else {

        cout << "Please choose one of the listed stats." << endl;
        continue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Why?

The conditionals expression is not evaluate as you think.  For example:

```
if (choice == "wisdom" || "Wisdom" || "Dexterity" || "dexterity" || "Strength" || "strength" || "Intelligence" || "intelligence"
    || "Charisma" || "charisma" || "Constitution" || "constitution")
```

first evaluates `choice == "wisdom"`.  If it's true the `if` clause is executed.  But if it's false, the next `||` term is evaluated, i.e.  `"Wisdom"` (not `choice== "Wisdom"`),  which is not null and hence is considered true.  So your condition will always be true.

You must be explicit on what you want to compare:

```
if (choice == "wisdom" || choice == "Wisdom" || choice == "Dexterity" ...)
```

### Isn't there a simpler way?

A simpler approach would be to pack the long list into a container,  for example a `set` and use a simple lookup:

```
set<string> possible_terms{"wisdom", "Wisdom", "Dexterity",... }; 
if (possible_terms.count(choice))
    ... // found 
else ... // not found
```

Another simplification, would be to lowercase the input and make all comparisons with lowercase words. This would be more robust and avoids that you have to foresee every possible case-combination in your code:

```
for (auto&c:choice) 
    c = tolower(c); 
...
if (choice == "wisdom" ) ... // works with "wisdom", "Wisdom", "WISDOM", "wiSDom" etc...
```